# Pandas ImportError 'cannot import name 'Int64Index' from 'pandas''

Tags: pandas, importerror, statsmodels

I am new to python! When i tried to import DeseqDataSet and DeseqStats from DeseqStats, an ImportError pops up.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/t5/\_4zcqb2d2vx91g45k05ry0ym0000gp/T/ipykernel_10055/4212347404.py in \<module\>
2 print(pd.__version__)
3 #from pydeseq2.dds import DeseqDataSet
\----\> 4 from pydeseq2.ds import DeseqStats

\~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydeseq2/ds.py in \<module\>
8 import numpy as np
9 import pandas as pd
\---\> 10 import statsmodels.api as sm  # type: ignore
11 from scipy.optimize import root_scalar  # type: ignore
12 from scipy.stats import f  # type: ignore

\~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/api.py in \<module\>
9 from . import regression
10 from .regression.linear_model import OLS, GLS, WLS, GLSAR
\---\> 11 from .regression.recursive_ls import RecursiveLS
12 from .regression.quantile_regression import QuantReg
13 from .regression.mixed_linear_model import MixedLM

\~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/recursive_ls.py in \<module\>
12
13 from statsmodels.tools.data import \_is_using_pandas
\---\> 14 from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel import (
15     MLEModel, MLEResults, MLEResultsWrapper, PredictionResults,
16     PredictionResultsWrapper)

\~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py in \<module\>
27
28 from statsmodels.base.data import PandasData
\---\> 29 import statsmodels.tsa.base.tsa_model as tsbase
30
31 from .news import NewsResults

\~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py in \<module\>
5 import warnings
6 import numpy as np
\----\> 7 from pandas import (to_datetime, Int64Index, DatetimeIndex, Period,
8                     PeriodIndex, RangeIndex, Timestamp, Series, Index,
9                     Float64Index, date_range, period_range)

ImportError: cannot import name 'Int64Index' from 'pandas'
```

I tried to use pip to uninstall pandas and statsmodels, as well as reinstall them. But it didn't work for me. What should I do with this scenario?

Comment: Try upgrading pandas to a version tht supports 'Int64Index' import

"pip install --upgrade pandas"

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this and the current version of my pandas is 2.1.3, but it still didn't work

Comment: What are the versions of "pydeseq2", "statsmodels" and other packages. Try updating all of them and let me know as well.

Comment: pydeseq2: 0.4.3     statsmodels:0.14.0

Comment: try downgrading the statsmodels to 0.13.0. "pip install statsmodels==0.13.0" or any version that is compatible to your pydeseq2

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to handle this `ImportError`:

### 1. Quickfix (not recommended)

It seems that when you try to import `pydeseq2.ds.DeseqStats`, it internally
imports a value from the `statsmodels.tsa.base.tsa_model` module.
This module however, tries to import `Int64Index` from `pandas`,
that is deprecated and was removed from newer versions of `pandas`.
To fix this issue without having to reinstall and update `pydeseq2`,
and `statsmodels`, you can add the following code on top of
the `from pydeseq2.ds import DeseqStats` import:

```py
import pandas
setattr(pandas, "Int64Index", pandas.Index)
setattr(pandas, "Float64Index", pandas.Index)

from pydeseq2.ds import DeseqStats
```

The above code will add two deprecated attributes named `Int64Index` and
`Float64Index` to the `pandas` module, that your `statsmodels` package version
requires. This will probably make the `statsmodels` module happy and will
allow you to import `pydeseq2.ds.DeseqStats` without further issues. However,
this solution is not recommended as it may cause other issues in the future.

### 2. Reinstall `pydeseq2` and `statsmodels`

Newer versions of `statsmodels` don't try to import `Int64Index` nor `Float64Index`
from `pandas` anymore. Looking at your traceback, it's unlikely that you're
really importing the version 0.14.0 of `statsmodels`. You can check the
version of `statsmodels`, as well as the version of `pydeseq2` by running
the following code:

```py
import statsmodels
print("statsmodels:", statsmodels.__version__)

import pydeseq2
print("pydeseq2:", pydeseq2.__version__)
```

Running the above code will inform you whether you're really using the version
0.14.0 of `statsmodels` or not.

Then, in a new terminal, you can run the following command to reinstall
both packages with the correct version:

```bash
pip install --force-reinstall statsmodels==0.14.0 pydeseq2==0.4.3
```

**Notes:** if you're running your code inside a Jupyter Notebook, remember to
restart the kernel after reinstalling the packages.

Now hopefully you should be able to import `pydeseq2.ds.DeseqStats` without
further issues.